# Can't connect to any WiFi Network after power off from button. Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager

I have an ASUS ROG 14 Laptop, running xubuntu 20.04. It was running OK until yesterday. I turned off the machine with the power button and now I can't connect to WiFi. Right now I am tethering USB trying to resolve the issue. I can connect to home WiFi from other devices like phone.

This is the output of wireless-info script: https://pastebin.com/ERwtLuf8

In particular I see this at the end:

```
[   51.357346] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Internetpellejero' [AC2]>       
[   51.376456] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Internetpellejero' [AC2]> (try 1/3)       
[   51.516483] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Internetpellejero' [AC2]> (try 2/3)     
[   51.672501] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Internetpellejero' [AC2]> (try 3/3)       
[   51.832481] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'Internetpellejero' [AC2]> timed out
```

Maybe an update of some package ? I really have lost many hours try to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try turning power management off and increasing the tx power

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by going back to a previous kernel version. I think the source of the issue was related by an unfortunate combination of versions (kernel + network manager + wpa_supplicant )